# CSS float "hug center"?

Tags: css, html, css-float, margins

I have two different divs, one that floats left and one that floats right. They are much smaller than the whole page (about 400x200 each) and so the two are far apart hugging the edges of the page. How can I get them next to each other in the center? I tried setting the margins to auto and about 20px, respectively, but it did not change anything..

Comment: Recreate your issue on http://jsfiddle.net/ and paste it with your question.

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for `inline-block`!

http://jsfiddle.net/hyw6P/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">Left!</div>
    <div id="right">Right!</div>
</div>​

#container{
text-align:center;
width:100%;
height:300px;
border:1px solid black
}
#left{
border:3px solid blue;
height:100px;
width:100px;
margin:auto;
display:inline-block;
}
#right{
border:3px solid red;
height:100px;
width:100px;
margin:auto;
display:inline-block;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

Give them a parent div with "margin: 0 auto; width:1000px;"

```
<div style="margin:0 auto; width:1000px;">
     <div style="float:left">Left</div>
     <div style="float:right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Or if you want them right next to each other:

```
<div style="margin:0 auto;">
     <div style="float:left">Left</div>
     <div style="float:left">Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you test this? It's not what the OP is after.

Comment: @j08691 of course I tested it, this is how i interpreted his request.

Answer (score 0):

Add a wrapper div around them both. Set a width on the wrapper and set margin top and bottom to 0 and the left and right to auto. Then set the width of the two float divs to fit the wrapper e.g. 50% will make them the same width.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a z-index and position absolutes, or relative

Heres a link to help ya out

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 610px; top: 80px; height: 400px; width: 100px; padding: 1em;">layer stuff</div>
```

http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/stylesheets/csslayout.html

http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a wrapper div and setting the child divs to display as inline-blocks.

CSS:

```
#a, #b{
    border: 1px solid #999;
    width: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
}
​#container {
    text-align:center;
}​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="a">a</div>
    <div id="b">b</div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5CtNd/)**.